# South data migration from parent class to subclass clobbers parent data

Tags: django, subclass, data-migration, django-south

I have a legacy Django model which is a little to specific in its implementation for my tastes.  I want to generate more specific subclasses of this model to handle differing scenarios, but want to retain a common base class for some common fields and methods.  Sample model is as follows:

```
class SomeOldClass(models.Model):
    sharedField1 = models.CharField('This is a shared field1', max_length=10)
    sharedField2 = models.CharField('This is a shared field2', max_length=10)
    specificField1 = models.CharField('This is a specific field1', max_length=10)
```

Ultimately, I am trying to break out a subclass of SomeOldClass that shares sharedField1 and sharedField2.

```
class SomeOldSubclass(SomeOldClass):
    specificField1_new = models.CharField('This is a specific field1', max_length=10)
```

Note the _new appended to the specificField1 in SomeOldSubclass due to errors creating a field with the same name as a parent.

My plan is to have three south scripts:

1. Schema migration to create the new
   app_someoldsubclass table
2. Data
   migration script to copy values from
   app_someoldclass.specificField1 to
   app_someoldsubclass.specificField1_new
3. Schema migration to drop
   specificField1 from app_someoldclass
   and rename specificField1_new to
   specificField1 in
   app_someoldsubclass

Sure, I could combine these scripts into one migration script, but bear with me.

With the classes as defined above, I created a schema migration script: `./manage.py schemamigration app --auto`

Then, I created an empy data migration script: `./manage.py datamigration app copy_values`

I modified the data migration script to add this in my forward method:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    "Write your forwards methods here."
    for soc in orm.SomeOldClass.objects.all():
        sosc = orm.SomeOldSubclass.objects.get_or_create(someoldclass_ptr=soc, specificField_new=soc.specificField1)
```

Note that because SomeOldSubclass inherits from SomeOldClass, I create a new SomeOldSubclass instance for each instance of SomeOldClass, and update the someoldclass_ptr and specificField1_new values.

Running the migrations creates a new row in app_someoldsubclass for each row in app_someoldclass as expected, with the value of specificField1_new the same as the same value in app_someoldclass.specificField1.  But, now all the fields in app_someoldclass are completely wiped out.  If I were to create an instance of the SomeOldClass model for an existing id, `sharedField1` would be `None`. In fact the only value that is still valid is the id in app_someoldclass.

In fact, the only way for app_someoldclass to retain its original values is to modify my forward method to the following:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    "Write your forwards methods here."
    for soc in orm.SomeOldClass.objects.all():
        sosc = orm.SomeOldSubclass.objects.get_or_create(someoldclass_ptr=soc, specificField_new=soc.specificField1)
        soc.save()
```

(note addition of **soc.save()**)

Is this expected behavior?  I would assume that since I am not modifying my instances of SomeOldClass as represented by the soc object, that there would be no need to save it again.  And even if I didn't save it, I surely wouldn't expect the data to get clobbered.

Is this a south thing?  A django thing?  A user error thing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in get_or_create. It is working differently than you expect to.

There are two ways to solve this:

- don't use get_or_create, or
- debug the problem

To debug the problem you should:

- read get_or_create documentation
- maybe read get_or_create implementation
- look at produced SQL statements

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but get_or_create will return me an instance of the object I am looking for that matches the parameters I pass in, creating one if it doesn't exist.  The reason I've been using get_or_create is due to the fact that newly created objects of type SomeOldSubclass could be created between the time of the original schema migration and the subsequent data migration.

Comment: Also, the problem I was seeing was that the instances of SomeOldClass (which I am only using to read values out of) are being wiped of their data while iterating through the list of orm.SomeOldClass.objects.all() unless I explicitly save the SomeOldClass instances.  Just seems odd to me that those instances should be modified in any way during a data migration if I don't make any explicit changes to them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in south, it's in your use of subclasses

When you save a subclass, it sets all the values in the database from its fields.
Your sosc object has been created with all of it's parent derived fields at their default values.

When you save the subclass, it overwrites the parent.
Then soc.save() resets the parent again to it's original values.

See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7623